# python - create dynamic URL for api call

Tags: python, api

Im trying to send a list of variables to another variable so i can send all items in the list to an api call, so curently I have

I have:

```
module = "a"
BASE_URL = "https://api-call.io/api"
API_KEY = "abcxyz"
url = BASE_URL + f"?module={module}&apikey={API_KEY}"
```

But I have 3 modules to send to api the api call and currently I create 3 urls

I want to create a list like:

```
module_list = ["a","b","c"]
```

And I want to send each item in the module list dynamically to the api call url 1 after the other instead of creating 3 urls

Comment: What do you mean by "send v1,v2,v3 to the module variable"?  Please give an example of what the `url` variable should contain.

Comment: Hey, I edited the question a bit to try to make more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over `module_list` like this:

```
module_list = ["a","b","c"]
BASE_URL = "https://api-call.io/api"
API_KEY = "abcxyz"

for module in module_list:
    url = BASE_URL + f"?module={module}&apikey={API_KEY}"
    # now call the url
```